# Can't publish test results to TFS 2010 - "Test run already uploaded"

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, nunit, tfsbuild

I am using Nunit4TeamBuild to try and publish the results of some unit tests back to TFS 2010.

When I try to publish a new test results XML the build is successful and it says the test results have been published. However there are no test results anywhere to be found in the build summary/log.

It even says "***No Test Results***" in the build summary beneath the compilation step.

So even though it was successful, it doesn't look like the test results actually get published.

But if I run another build definition that just takes a test result XML and publish it, I get this error:

> Test run already uploaded.

So it would seem that the test results *were*, in fact, published to TFS. But where? How can I see them? Why don't they show up in the build summary/log like it's meant to? I cannot find the results anywhere.

Comment: @waka If you are going to edit someone's post, don't be a grammar Nazi... Where does it say not to use contractions? And there was absolutely no reason to make those edits in my second & third last paragraph. In fact, I'd argue that some of your changes actually serve to worsen the paragraphs.

Comment: How did you publish test result?

Comment: @J.Doe: I edited your post from the "Help & Improvement" Review Queue because someone has flagged it as "Needs Improvement". If you disagree with the changes I made you can simply [roll them back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18876/369311). No need to call someone a "grammar nazi", this may be considered rude by some.